# What is a "tenant" or "tenancy" in SharePoint Apps?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I've been hearing a lot of "tenant" or "tenancy" in the SharePoint Apps world, but seems no one has ever explained it clearly. This confuses me when I start to develop SharePoint Apps. Does any one can explain what is a "tenant" or "tenancy" in SharePoint Apps in a simple way? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Tenant is roughly equivalent to a Web Application.

I Googled "What is a SharePoint Tenant" and came up with this link:

[SharePoint Online Farm Multitenancy](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/sharepoint-online-farm-multitenancy.html)

[image]

Comment: Probably I just don't understand why they do this which will increase the already complex solutions. Anyway, thanks Rob!

Comment: @Jony This model is for hosting cloud services.  You would not set up an environment like this unless you planned on 'renting' out parts of the tenant.